# mockk, which one to use for calling a un stubbed function on the mock

Tags: mockk

having a class:

```
class ClassType {
      fun func(v: Int) : Int{
            return v * 2
     }
}
```

if it has mocked the class:

```
val mock = mockk<ClassType>()
```

and does not want to change the func()'s behavior, i.e `mock.func(5) == 10`
what is the difference between

```
every { mock.func(any()) } just Runs
```

and

```
every { mock.func(any()) } andAnswer { callOriginal() }
```

?

Answer (score 1):

None of the expressions from your question are correct, but you are close.
The first expression

```
every { mock.func(any()) } just Runs
```

is only applicable for a function `func` that returns `Unit`. As the name suggests, the expression mocks the function `mock.func` to *just run* without any side effects, that is, to do nothing.

The second doesn't appear to be correct MockK syntax. There is an `andAnswer` in EasyMock, but not in MockK, where there is `answers`.
The expression

```
every { mock.func(any()) } answers { callOriginal() }
```

tells the mock that any call to `func` with any argument should just call the original implementation in `ClassType`.